# Concatenate netcdf files with different variables - using nco

Tags: netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I want to concatenate two sets of netcdf files using `nco`, where each set has about 30 files.

Set 1 contains: longitude, latitude, time and v.

Set 2 contains: longitude, latitude, time and u.

I have tried:

```
ncks *.nc out.nc
```

but I get:

> Error received 97 filenames; need no more than two

then I tried:

```
ncks -A *.nc out.nc
```

but the error persists:

> Error received 97 filenames; need no more than two

Please can you point me in the right direction, I am quite new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your first try should work if you use [ncrcat](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncrcat) instead of `ncks`:

```
ncrcat *.nc out.nc
```

And be careful that your wildcard expression evaluates to the files you intend, i.e., that `ls *.nc` results in all input files and nothing else.

Comment: My apologies for only getting back to you now @Charlie Zender, but I have been out of office. There seems to be a problem with the data on my side, so I will accept this answer.

Comment: This would work on each set separately but not with a mixture of them. Attempt to merge files with different variables leads to 

ERROR: nco_inq_varid() reports requested variable "XXX" is not defined in file

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you can also use [Climate Data Operators (CDO)](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki):

```
cdo cat *.nc out.nc
```

assuming all files are on the same grid and times.

Answer (score 1):

You can only append one variable at at time, so `-A *.nc` is invalid.

If you have `var1.nc`, `var2.nc`, `var3.nc` with common dimensions and sizes, try:

```
cp var1.nc out.nc
ncks -h -A var2.nc out.nc
ncks -h -A var3.nc out.nc
# repeat as needed
```

This will combine them into one `out.nc` file, leaving the original files unmodified.